# Javascript Question: Misunderstand either getElementbyID or innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why, with the following code, when I click "Click Here", the text doesn't change to "test"?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div id="thisdiv" onClick="document.getElementbyID('thisdiv').innerHTML='test'">Click Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Carnotaurus: You only need `javascript:` in links (in the URI), never put it in event handlers (it is not wrong, but does not make sense to do so). `;` is only needed if you want to execute multiple statements. [`innerHTML` is pretty much supported by all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t03). jQuery is not the answer to everything.

Comment: @Carnotaurus: If `innerHTML` isn't supported on all browsers, what good will it do to switch to jQuery since jQuery relies on `innerHTML`?

Comment: Sorry but I wasn't going to suggest using innerHTML

Comment: @Carnotaurus: You deleted your comment, but you stated that `innerHTML` isn't supported in all browsers, then suggested jQuery instead. jQuery uses `innerHTML` so if a browser doesn't have it, jQuery won't work.

Comment: What I wrote is addressed in Felix's comment. I deleted it because it was misleading, as he is correct in what he wrote. Sorry again but you have misrepresented position. I did not suggest using innerHTML in jQuery or otherwise. I would have suggested adding DOM child elements through jQuery which have no dependency whatsoever on innerHTML. So, you are wholly incorrect on that score and I do not appreciate having to reiterate this for a second time.

Comment: @Carnotaurus: You're not reading what I wrote. Where did I say that you suggested using innerHTML? I'll repeat *again* what I wrote. jQuery uses innerHTML. It relies on it. It is used in its source several times. When you use jQuery, you **are** using innerHTML. If innerHTML isn't there, jQuery is broken. Suggesting jQuery as a fix for a browser that doesn't support innerHTML doesn't make sense. jQuery doesn't support all browsers. It supports **IE 6.0+, FF 2+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.0+, Chrome**. All of those browsers have innerHTML.

Comment: jQuery doesn't wholly on innerHTML. Please go do a search for other ways of dynamically inserting tags into a document without using innerHTML - Ta

Comment: @Carnotaurus: Uh, yeah. I'm very familiar. That doesn't change the fact that jQuery relies on innerHTML, and is broken without it. But you don't honestly care, so never mind I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure you know what you are trying to say. So, I will waste no more time on the matter, which now has precious little to do with the initial question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lowercase `b` and an uppercase `D`.

```
 //-------v------should be uppercase
getElementById
 //----------^---should be lowercase
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qSEpF/

---

But simpler would be to reference the current element with `this`:

```
onClick="this.innerHTML='test'"
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qSEpF/1/

Comment: and an uppercase "D"... it should be lowercase

Comment: @patrick dw: :) (*I deleted my comment as it is no longer relevant*) +1

Comment: @Felix: Thanks. I was a little hasty there at first. :o)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case-sensitive, as Patrick pointed out. And, let's be honest: Intellisense for JavaScript pretty much blows. Be very careful when writing script.

What likely happened is that when you attempted to invoke the method with the wrong case, JavaScript couldn't find it on the inheritance change and created it instead, with the wrong case. That would explain why you got no script error, and nothing happened.

Comment: I'll bet there are errors, but OP didn't have the console open. When attempting to invoke a non-existent method, you'll get a `TypeError` stating something like *"...has no such method getElementbyID"*.